# Yaml script to download the most recent Artifact from Artifact repository

Tags: yaml, artifactory, continuous-deployment

I need to write an yaml script to get the most recent artifact from artifact repository and store it in a windows server.

Repository Browser Structure would be like the below

Name of the Repo - Generic_App
TEST_APP is a folder inside the repo.

Generic_App->TEST_APP->1->TEST_APP-1.ZIP

Generic_App->TEST_APP->2->TEST_APP-2.ZIP

Generic_App->TEST_APP->3->TEST_APP-3.ZIP

Can you help me with the script to download TEST_APP-3.ZIP

Answer (score 2):

You requested for a yaml script. I guess it'll be easy for you to embed the following command in any script you may be using.

The following JFrog CLI command downloads the latest file from Artifactory, which matches your requirements. The command will look for the newest file created, which path and name matches the following pattern (notice the wildcard in the file name pattern) -

> Generic_App/TEST_APP/TEST_APP-*.ZIP

```
jfrog rt dl "Generic_App/TEST_APP/TEST_APP-*.ZIP" --sort-by created --sort-order desc --limit 1 --url "<artifactory url>" --user "<artifactory username>" --password "<artifactory password>"
```

Note: In most cases, the Artifactory URL ends with **/artifactory**

If the machine which runs the script doesn't have JFrog CLI installed, here's how you can install it - https://jfrog.com/getcli/